# Create new Word document with macro in C#

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word

I made an add-in for Word 2010 in visual studio 2010 (C#), which dynamicly adds new buttons to a new ribbon tab (data from sql database). Now when i click on a button, a new document with a macro needs to be opend. I have the needed macro in a document (.docm), and the path to it is in the database.

**How do I create a new document with the macro from another document?**

Comment: Fixed it, this is the solution:
`//create new document, location = path to template
Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Add(location);
//auto run macro
doc.RunAutoMacro(WdAutoMacros.wdAutoOpen);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's been *months* since this question has had a formal answer, so for the record, on Apr 5th 2011, bruggesboy spake thusly:

Fixed it, this is the solution:

```
    //create new document, location = path to template
    Document doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Add(location);
    //auto run macro 
    doc.RunAutoMacro(WdAutoMacros.wdAutoOpen);
```

And behold, there were word documents with macro's running about.